# Novel where a bunch of teenagers play a board game that gives some of them powers and turns one into some kind of octopus (not Interstellar Pig)

Tags: story-identification, novel

My friend lent me this book in the early '90s, so it must've been from the '80s. It's a teen novel where a bunch of teenagers end up in an old house to play some kind of board game.  They gain the powers from their character in the game; one of them even turns into some kind of octopus. I remember one of the teens had the power to create water or ice.  I know it's a long shot, but I have been searching for this book for years with no success.

*Edit:  it's not interstellar pig, but the story is kind of similar, I think they are trapped in the house as well?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall anything about the cover of this book?

Comment: I had to check if there is a third one after Zathura but no, doesn't seem so.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions a sequel to _Interstellar Pig_, but doesn't really give much information...  maybe that?

Answer (score 10):

Might you be recalling [*Interstellar Pig*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6576) (1984) by William Sleator?

[image: Cover of "Interstellar Pig" showing Barney standing on a cosmic chess board with life-sized statues of alien races as pieces]

The [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_Pig#Plot) on Wikipedia notes:

> When Zena, Manny, and Joe move into the cinder-block cottage next door, Barney is intrigued by their glamorous, exotic lifestyle. His fascination grows when Zena introduces Barney to their favorite pastime: **Interstellar Pig, a board game** in which the key objective is to finish the game with the Piggy card in hand.
>
> Zena quickly briefs him on the rules: each player picks their character from a box of cards depicting different aliens. Every alien race has its own strengths, weaknesses, and IRSC (Interstellar Relative Sapience Code, with lower numbers favorable). When the time runs out, every home planet will be obliterated except the one belonging to the holder of the Piggy. Barney is amazed when the neighbors keep choosing the same character cards: Joe repeatedly picks water-breathing Jrlb; Zena always chooses Zulma, an arachnoid nymph; and Manny always picks **Moyna, an octopus-like gas bag**.

Comment: The opening of the first paragraph that you did not include is really something